# PHP Login in mobile webview

Tags: php, android, authentication, webview

I have a mobile app developed with Titanium and this app has a webview component that loads my website (PHP website).

I need to login the user on my PHP website using data posted from the APP. What I did is simple:

- Checking if there are post variables filled;
- Using those login data posted and calling my login function;

On iPhone this works well. On Android, I can login but I lose my session/cookies after navigating on my website inside webview.

I discovered that if I login using my login form (on Android), the session will work fine. So the problem may be linked to calling the login function directly.

Does anyone knows the best approach to make this work?

Comment: Probably best to include some code so we can see what the issue is. Hard to debug something like that without seeing it.